# How can I get access to a variable in a View which was created in a Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I get access to a variable in a View which was created in a Controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the variable to the view in the ViewModel (the parameter to the `View()` method) or the TempData dictionary.

Comment: You're right. I try to do it next: `var res = calculator.Div(19.2, 23.3); return View(res);` And in view I try to show this variable with @res. But I receive error "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'res' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @misho: That sets the `Model` to your value.

Comment: @misho: The parameter you pass to the `View` method becomes the `Model` property in the view.

Answer (score 10):

Either put the variable into the Model that you are using for your View

Or use a ViewBag variable - e.g. from http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<string> colors = new List<string>();
    colors.Add("red");
    colors.Add("green");
    colors.Add("blue");

    ViewBag.ListColors = colors; //colors is List
    ViewBag.DateNow = DateTime.Now;
    ViewBag.Name = "Hajan";
    ViewBag.Age = 25;
    return View(); 
}
```

and

```
<p>
    My name is 
    <b><%: ViewBag.Name %></b>, 
    <b><%: ViewBag.Age %></b> years old.
    <br />    
    I like the following colors:
</p>
<ul id="colors">

<% foreach (var color in ViewBag.ListColors) { %>
    <li>
        <font color="<%: color %>"><%: color %></font>
    </li>
<% } %>
```

although hopefully you'll be using Razor :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to the ViewData[] dictionary or the (newer) ViewBag dynamic.

In your controller:

```
ViewData['YourVariable'] = yourVariable;
// or
ViewBag.YourVariable = yourVariable;
```

In your view:

```
<%: ViewData["yourVariable"] %>
// or
<%: ViewBag.YourVariable %>
```